# MySQLDump issue with a special characters

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, mysqldump, windows

Code:
use test;

CREATE TABLE Test_user(Username VARCHAR(15),path VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO Test_user VALUES('new1','C:\newfolder\one.xlsx');
INSERT INTO Test_user VALUES('new1','C:/newfolder/one.xlsx');

I have created a .sql file using MySQLDump, which has contents

Filename : Table1.sql

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_user`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `test_user` (
  `Username` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `test_user` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `test_user` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `test_user` VALUES ('new1','C:\newfolderone.xlsx'),('new1','C:/newfolder/one.xlsx');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `test_user` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

in the above Table1.sql file ('new1','C:\newfolderone.xlsx') backslash before one.xlsx is not displaying , While trying to execute this file, i am getting output like this

new1    C:ewfolderone.xlsx
new2    C:/newfolder/one.xlsx

Where it is not displaying \ at all , suggest me how to resolve it and also what are special characters like this backslash will create this kind of bug.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Would you please format your question so that it’s readable? Code should be indented at least four spaces so that it is rendered in a monospace font and newlines are preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [string literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) in MySQL.

There you’ll learn that a backslash character is used to escape some special strings, and to have literal backslashes in your strings (as in Windows pathnames), you have to double them:

```
INSERT INTO test_user VALUES ('new1','C:\\newfolderone.xlsx');
```

The complete list of characters in need of a special treatment is at the above link.

However, it is best to have the intermediate language deal with such problems. For instance, in PHP you would call [`PDO::quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php); other platforms and languages provide similar facilities.